# Why is the following code giving me an error about an abstract class?

Tags: c++, abstract-class

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Vehicle
{
public:
    Vehicle() {};
    virtual ~Vehicle() {};
    virtual void Move() = 0;
    virtual void Haul() = 0;
};

class Car : public Vehicle
{
public:
    Car() {};
    virtual ~Car() {};
    virtual void Move(int m) { cDist = m;
    cout << "Vehicle moves " << cDist << " miles/hour\n"; }
    virtual void Haul() { cout << "Car's Hauling!\n"; }
private:
    int cDist;
};

class Bus : public Car
{
public:
    Bus() {};
    virtual ~Bus() {};
    void Move(int m) { Move(m); }
    void Haul() { "Bus is Hauling!\n"; }
};

int main()
{
    Vehicle* ptCar = new Car;
    Vehicle* ptBus = new Bus;
    ptCar->Move(1000);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

guys, why this code is giving me errors when trying to instantiate an object of Car, and Bus in main. I didn't intended to create an abstract class of Car and Bus, only of Vehicle...
any help appreciated

```
1>------ Build started: Project: OperatorsTypes, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  main.cpp
1>c:\users\jorge\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\shapes\operatorstypes\operatorstypes\main.cpp(36): error C2259: 'Car' : cannot instantiate abstract class
1>          due to following members:
1>          'void Vehicle::Move(void)' : is abstract
1>          c:\users\jorge\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\shapes\operatorstypes\operatorstypes\main.cpp(9) : see declaration of 'Vehicle::Move'
1>c:\users\jorge\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\shapes\operatorstypes\operatorstypes\main.cpp(37): error C2259: 'Bus' : cannot instantiate abstract class
1>          due to following members:
1>          'void Vehicle::Move(void)' : is abstract
1>          c:\users\jorge\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\shapes\operatorstypes\operatorstypes\main.cpp(9) : see declaration of 'Vehicle::Move'
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: First, method names should begin with lower case letters (by convention). Second, how is this not an infinite loop? `void Move(int m) { Move(m); }`

Comment: The convention that upper starting variables with upper case means it's a class name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Move` function in your derived classes have a different signature (they both take an `int`).

To fix it, add an `int` parameter in the base class as well.

```
virtual void Move(int m) = 0
```

Answer (score 3):

`Car` is abstract because it does not override the pure virtual `void Vehicle::Move()`.

`void Car::Move(int)` does not override `void Vehicle::Move()` because its parameter list is different.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing the parameter m in super class. In Vehicle

```
virtual void Move(int) = 0;  // add the int
```

In C++ with function overloading, aMethod() and aMethod(aArgument) are not same.

Answer (score 2):

`Move` takes 0 arguments in the abstract `Vehicle` class and an `int` argument in `Bus` and `Car` so they are different functions. Change the prototype in `Vehicle` to

```
virtual void Move(int) = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error indicates, `Car` and `Bus` are abstract because you did not override `void Vehicle::Move()` in them. `Move(int)` is a different function.